# How To Deploy NodeJS REST API To AZURE Cloud

Tags: node.js, rest, api, azure, cloud

I'm trying to deploy my nodejs rest api application to my azure cloud, but i fail again and again.

I get HTTP 500 response.

"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

**My AZURE FTP (What I Uploaded) :**

[image]

**web.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode"
           path="app.js"
           verb="*"
           modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="NodeInspector"
              patternSyntax="ECMAScript"
              stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                 matchType="IsFile"
                 negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

**URLs**

**Request** : localhost/api/user/getcategories/5c141fa7498f3605c8b2cf34

**Response** :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "categories": [
        {
            "_id": "5c141fab498f3605c8b2cf35",
            "name": "OTHER"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

**Request** : https://**.azurewebsites.net/api/user/getcategories/5c141fa7498f3605c8b2cf34

**Response** : The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Comment: I solved this problem by adding NodeJS version to 'Application Settings' panel.
WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION, 8.9.4

Answer (score 1):

If you access your Azure App Service pane for the web app, under Development Tools you should have a "Advanced Tools". Select it and then hit "go" to access Kudu.

[Kudu Advanced Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yttP.png)

You can then go to the "Debug Console" dropdown to access your preferred shell. From here you should be able to access the server logs and see what errors are being thrown.